# Splitting a string into a dictionary VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string, dictionary, split

Here's my string:

```
gamename\jbnightfire\hostname\testserver\hostport\26015
```

I'm trying to split this string into a dictionary(of string, string). Please note that this string is not static and could contain many more keys and values.

The dictionary would contain the following:

```
key = gamename, value = jbnightfire
key = hostname, value = testserver
key = hostport, value = 26015
```

I've tried at least 5 different methods and can't seem to get any that work. It should be extremely simple, but for the life of me I cannot get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post at least 1 of the methods you have tried here?

Comment: After each attempt I've deleted the code

Comment: I finally came up with a solution that works, it may not be the best solution but it works.

    Dim stringtosplit as string = "gamename\jbnightfire\hostname\testserver\hostport\26015"
    Dim dictionary1 as New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim spl = stringtosplit.Split("\")
    Dim temp As String = ""
    Dim temp2 As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To spl1.Length - 1
       If temp.Length = 0 Then
           temp = spl(i)
       Else
           temp2 = spl(i)
           dictionary1.Add(temp, temp2)
          temp = ""
       End If
    Next

Comment: Please don't post code in a comment.  Edit your question and post the code there.

Comment: The more I think about it I think the following format is the safest key-wise: gamename, gamename\jbnightfire, gamename\jbnightfire\hostname etc, that way the keys will be unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string and loop through it with a step of 2 to advance 2 items at a time. That means the key would be at index `i`, and `i + 1` would be the value.

```
Dim input = "gamename\jbnightfire\hostname\testserver\hostport\26015"
Dim split = input.Split(New String() { "\" },
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

For i As Integer = 0 To split.Length - 1 Step 2
    dict.Add(split(i), split(i + 1))
Next
```

Note that the above approach uses the `Add` method, which will throw an exception if a duplicate key exists. Use the above approach if you don't expect duplicates.

Alternately, you may assign the value directly to key, in which case it will overwrite any existing value if the key exists:

```
dict(split(i)) = split(i + 1)
```

Another option is to use `ContainsKey` and skip it if it exists, or perform some additional logic to determine whether to skip it or keep it. For example, this will skip it if it already exists:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To split.Length - 1 Step 2
    If dict.ContainsKey(split(i)) Then Continue For
    dict.Add(split(i), split(i + 1))
Next
```

Comment: This correct but dangerous. You should check if each value is already in the dictionary. If you try and add a value twice you will have an exception. if not dict.containskey(value) then dict.add(value)

Comment: @trucker_jim that's a good point. The OP will need to decide whether to check and skip, as you've shown, or overwrite the value.

Comment: Yeah the more I think about it I think the following format is the safest key-wise: gamename, gamename\jbnightfire, gamename\jbnightfire\hostname etc, that way the keys will be unique

Comment: @trucker_jim updated my post to account for possible duplicates

Comment: Mostly works for me, but I think this should probably be 0 to To split.Length - 2 - That way it skips over the last value if for some reason there is an odd number of parameters.